# what can cause files to dissapear from a web site?

Tags: php, security, pdo

Recently files have started to disappear from my site. I am losing hundreds of documents. Nothing in the site has changed, and its about 3 years old. On top of that entries in the database are also being removed. The tables are not entirely empty but perhaps 30% are removed. Same with the files, but perhaps 95% are removed.

I thought I am getting hacked, so my solution has been to change all the mysqli statements to prepared PDO statements.

I hope this works, but if not, what else could be causing this, and what other preventative measures should I consider?

Comment: Have you done some basic troubleshooting? Disk space? Anything like that? All we can do is guess, given what you've given us.

Comment: My web host pulled some sort of a rollback once, making new entries disappear. Could that be it?

Comment: Switching to prepared statements is a good practice to prevent future attacks, but likely won't change anything for an already compromised server. It sounds like you may be getting hit by ransomware. I hope you have good backups that can't be overwritten from your server.

Comment: It's a private server, not shared hosting, and nothing has changed. I think it's hacked, so I am trying to do everything to increase security.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your server has been hacked, you should contact your hosting customer support, change all passwords, check for problems in your site use CHMOD 0755 for folders (never use CHMOD 0777 for your folders), if you use a database, than do NOT use old sql code, update it to PDO or MySQLi

You can try another server as well, buy a hosting package from other hosting company, create an A record for test.example.com (Where example.com should be your domain!) point it to the IP on your test hosting package at the other company and create it as a domain at the new hosting service.

I hope this will be helpful to you..